# can someone help me with this mysql code

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert some data , but it doesn't work, I´m learning databases with SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE INSTITUTO2;
USE INSTITUTO2;

CREATE TABLE Alumnos (
    Num_Alumno CHAR (4) ,
    Nombre CHAR (15),
    Apellidos CHAR (20),
    Dirección CHAR (30),
    Telefono CHAR (9),
    CP CHAR (14),
    Email CHAR(20)
    );
CREATE TABLE Asignaturas (
    Cod_Asignatura CHAR (2),
    Nombre CHAR(30),
    Creditos INT (2)
    );

CREATE TABLE Matricula (
    Num_Alumno CHAR (4),
    Cod_Asignatura CHAR (2),
    Nota_1EVA INT (2),
    Nota_2EVA INT (2),
    Nota_Junio INT (2),
    Nota_Septiembre FLOAT (6,2)
    );

ALTER TABLE Alumnos ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(Num_Alumno);
ALTER TABLE Alumnos MODIFY Telefono CHAR (9) NOT NULL;



ALTER TABLE Alumnos ADD CHECK (CP BETWEEN 28000 AND 28999);

ALTER TABLE Asignaturas ADD PRIMARY KEY PK_CODASIGNATURA (Cod_Asignatura);
ALTER TABLE Asignaturas MODIFY  Creditos INT (2) NOT NULL; 


ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD PRIMARY KEY PK_MATA (Num_Alumno,Cod_Asignatura); /

ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_NUMAL (Num_Alumno) REFERENCES Alumnos (Num_Alumno)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE; 
ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_CODIGOSASIG (Cod_Asignatura)REFERENCES Asignaturas (Cod_Asignatura)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


INSERT INTO Alumnos VALUES('0001','Oscar','Gonzalez','Mayor,5','911234567','28801','oscar@yahoo.es');
INSERT INTO Alumnos VALUES('0002','Miguel','Ortiz','Princesa,4','913216549','28804','Miguel@terra.es');
INSERT INTO Alumnos (Num_Alumno, Nombre,Apellidos ,Dirección ,Telefono ,CP) 
    VALUES('0003','Jose','Gomez','Salamanca,3','918794568','28805');    
INSERT INTO Alumnos VALUES('0004','Gema','Lopez','Mayor,8','918754981','28801','gema@terra.es');
INSERT INTO Alumnos (Num_Alumno, Nombre,Apellidos ,Dirección ,Telefono ,CP) 
    VALUES('0005','Javiel','Alonso','Ibiza,37','91875875','28814'); 


INSERT INTO Asignaturas (Cod_Asignatura, Nombre,Creditos)
        VALUES                  ('SI','Sistemas','8'),
                                ('PL','Programacion','12'),
                                ('AN','Analisis','10'),
                                ('RL','Redes locales','12'),
                                ('BD','Bases de datos','10');

INSERT INTO Matricula (Num_Alumno, Cod_Asignatura, Nota_1EVA, Nota_2EVA, Nota_Junio)
    VALUES                      ('003','AN','7','7','7'),
                                ('003','PL','6','6','6');
```

I don't understand because I type first asignaturas table....thank u too much

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`instituto2`.`matricula`, CONSTRAINT `matricula_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Num_Alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`Num_Alumno`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Format the code.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: sorry, I'm learning and not yet established correctly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last INSERT, you are missing one '0'.

```
INSERT INTO Matricula (Num_Alumno, Cod_Asignatura, Nota_1EVA, Nota_2EVA, Nota_Junio)
VALUES ('0003','AN','7','7','7'), ('0003','PL','6','6','6');
```

Comment: I would not see it after days ... thank you very very much : D

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can include the Primary and Foreign key constraints inside the table itself to avoid unnecessary code that might make things more complicated.
So your tables can become like this (also keep in mind to have a well written and formatted code). I will also use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR` because its much better in terms of memory allocation and data integrity.

```
CREATE TABLE Alumnos( 
Num_Alumno VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
Nombre VARCHAR(15), 
Apellidos VARCHAR(20), 
Dirección VARCHAR(30), 
Telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
CP VARCHAR(14), 
Email VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(Num_Alumno)
); 

CREATE TABLE Asignaturas( 
Cod_Asignatura VARCHAR (2), 
Nombre VARCHAR(30), 
Creditos INT(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Cod_Asignatura)
);

CREATE TABLE Matricula( 
Num_Alumno VARCHAR(4), 
Cod_Asignatura VARCHAR(2), 
Nota_1EVA INT(2), 
Nota_2EVA INT(2),
Nota_Junio INT(2), 
Nota_Septiembre FLOAT(6,2),
PRIMARY KEY(Num_Alumno,Cod_Asignatura),
CONSTRAINT ForeignKey1
    FOREIGN KEY (Num_Alumno) 
    REFERENCES Alumnos (Num_Alumno)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT ForeignKey1
    FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Asignatura)
    REFERENCES Asignaturas(Cod_Asignatura)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

And now assuming that you are done creating your database and your tables, you are ready to make some `inserts`. Beware the fact that you cant add values that are Foreign Keys of other tables, if that keys do not already exist. Thus you have to keep a right order in your inserts.

UPDATE: I tested your `Inserts` on MySQL Workbench. Your problem is that you are referring to Foreign Keys that do not exists in your database. More precisely you are writing:

```
INSERT INTO Matricula (Num_Alumno, Cod_Asignatura, Nota_1EVA, Nota_2EVA, Nota_Junio) 
VALUES ('003','AN','7','7','7'), ('003','PL','6','6','6');
```

instead of

```
        Error                      Error
VALUES ('0003','AN','7','7','7'), ('0003','PL','6','6','6');
```

Advice: its a nice practice now that you are learning to make use of ALTER in that way to see its capabilities, but try to avoid it when you are creating your own database. ALTER servers the purpose of making a change in a database that we would like to keep its integrity regarding to data and other means.

In conclusion. Keep up the practice, and try to write cleaner code! Also pay attention to the errors as they always point out what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you very much, what a difference!!!, obviously it looks much more clearly formatted in the way you propose, I understand what you said, they helped me a lot, I was not able to see the error, and I will get used to formatting the code so that you can read as well as take into account the points you indicate, thank you very much again!!